# Remove illegal character from JSON before deserializing with JSON.NET

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net, json-deserialization

I have a string like which I want deserialize to datatable. Because it has a double quote in the value `JSON.NET` is not able to deserialize this.

```
[{"name":"soham "the" dasgupta"}]
```

Now I would like to replace the `"the"` with `the`. Please help. `Replace("\"", "")` is not working obviously.

Comment: What if you do `Replace("\"the\"", "the")` or can be other string than "the" between the double quotes?

Comment: This is plain wrong JSON. If you have any influence on the code either because you wrote it or you can contact the producer of this kinda sad thing you should fix or let it be fixed. Every other solution will make you crazy.

Comment: your "json" is not a valid json. If you need to replace "the" with the just do it as mentioned above by @croxy

Comment: why don't you use RegEX to do this....and Replace any thing between two colon(:) sign which is under " "...

Comment: @dryman I don't have control over the code. And I also don't know what words they may be sending within double quotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically you need to find the characters between the quotes and check if they are valid JSON delimiters.

I've wrote a quick and dirty function which searches the substrings between the strings and matches them with valid JSON delimiters. If the substring don't match, it escapes the quotes.

Note: This code is an very basic example of my idea, it could possibly not deal with every kind of JSON input.

```
static string FixJson(string input)
{
    var output = input;
    for (var x = 0; x < input.Length; x++)
    {
        if (input[x] != '\"') continue;

        for (var y = x + 1; y < input.Length; y++)
        {
            if (input[y] != '\"') continue;

            var found = false;
            for (var z = y + 1; z < input.Length; z++)
            {
                if (input[z] != '\"') continue;

                var tmp = input.Substring(y + 1, z - y - 1);
                if (tmp.Any(t => t != ' ' && t != ':' && t != ',' && t != '{' && t != '}'))
                {
                    output = output.Replace("\"" + tmp + "\"", "\\\"" + tmp + "\\\"");
                }

                x = y;
                found = true;
                break;
            }

            if (found)
                break;
        }
    }

    return output;
}
```

Comment: With your input it returns: `[{"name":"soham \"the\" dasgupta"}]`

Comment: This output will be deserialized with Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject, provide please what result you try to obtain?